# How to search for inner items in nested recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, full-text-search, android-adapter

I've created a nested recycler view as per my requirement and it works fine. But now I want to search inner list items(child recycler view). But it doesn't work properly.

Here is the method for custom search filter inside child adapter.

```
    public class CustomSearchFilter extends Filter {
        CategoryItemsAdapter adapter;
        List<CategoryItemsModel> filterList;

        public CustomSearchFilter(List<CategoryItemsModel> filterList, CategoryItemsAdapter adapter) {
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.filterList = filterList;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                ArrayList<CategoryItemsModel> filteredPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++) {
                    if (filterList.get(i).getCategoryItemName().toLowerCase().contains(((String) constraint).toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredPlayers.add(filterList.get(i));
                    }
                }

                results.count = filteredPlayers.size();
                results.values = filteredPlayers;
            } else {
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;

            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            categoryItemArrayList = (ArrayList<CategoryItemsModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Implement **Filterable** on the class level to override method below.

```
  @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new CustomSearchFilter(categoryItemArrayList, this);
        }
        return filter;
    }
```

In my fragment in the **OnActivityCreated** method, I implement **addTextChangedListener** via editext like this:

```
   edtSearchMenu.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                try {
                    text = edtSearchMenu.text.toString().toLowerCase()
                    innerItemsAdapter?.filter?.filter(text)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

How can I search inner items in nested recycler view?